# Is there a better way to persist redux state data for a production environment than redux persist

Tags: reactjs, redux, redis

Redux persist has been a great tool to persist the necessary redux state values, but it feels like it isn't the most ideal set up for a production application. I may be mistaking, but I guess I'm envisioning using redis to save the state and a session id value in a cookie to retrieve that and rehydrate manually(?) as needed.

I have redis set up in my application, I'm just not sure what the next step is in moving my persisted redux store from being saved in localStorage by redux persist to saving it in redis and retrieving it manually.

Does this make sense? Does anybody have any references or information I can use to achieve this?